# "He would have done anything you [would ask/would have asked/had asked] him to"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verb-agreement, simple-past

I want to say "He'll do anything you ask him to" but in the past tense, as that was the case 10 years ago, but he's not like that anymore. Which of the following should I use?

> 1. He would have done anything you **would ask** him to!
> 2. He would have done anything you **would have asked** him to!
> 3. He would have done anything you **had asked** him to!

Which is correct or otherwise preferable?

Comment: They're all *way* too "complicated". Just Simple Past will do fine - *Back then, he would / he'd do anything you **asked** [him to]*.

Comment: Yeah I was about to say. "He would have done had would have asked have had him do anything you have had would have done would have". Like, who even talks like that. Who even writes like that. Nobody, ever, that's who. He'd do anything you asked, but even he would never write like that.

Comment: From FumbleFingers answer, I've realized your question might be a bit ambiguous. FF's answer is the right one, if that's the meaning you're looking for. Your answer 3 is also correct, but functions like a past conditional. It's implicit that you didn't ask him to do something. Perhaps it's too late now: it's a pity, because he would have done anything you had asked him.

Comment: FumbleFingers' answer is only clear if you keep the "back then". Say you only said "He would do anything you asked him to" can also means he would now do it. "If you asked me help you, I would do it." This doesn't necessarily refer to the past. I'm trying to think if there's a tense or construction you can use without specifying a point in time such as "back then".

Comment: @RegDwigнt A lot of people talk like that. Well, not your exaggerated example, of course, which is ungrammatical, but all three examples in the question are perfectly natural and highly likely to be heard in regular conversation, with the appropriate contractions, of course. “He’da done anything you’d ask/you’d asked/you’da asked him to” (AmE) is perfectly commonplace.

Answer (score 1):

> He would do anything you asked him to.

"Would" is the past tense of "will".

Comment: This still isn't clear it's referring back to the past. Take for example: "I would do anything you asked me to." I'm not sure there's a simple way to do this clearly without adding extra information as FumbleFingers did, with "back then he would do..."

Comment: To Zebrafish Whats then the difference between these two?

Comment: I would have done anything you HAD ASKED me to! & I would do anything you asked me to!

Comment: @J.J. The first is referring to the past, the second is referring to now. Things are complicated though, because you can't tell always from the tense used. "would have done" in grammars is called the conditional perfect or past conditional.  "I would do" is called the simple conditional or present conditional. However just to make things more confusing, there's nothing conditional about the following sentence: "I would wash the dishes and he would rinse them." This likely means some time ago I washed the dishes and he rinsed them."

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of the employment of a tense, which conveys your intended meaning. The closest I can get to one is:

> "He would have done anything you asked him to."

Though this may not be totally immune to misconstrual, as it may suggest contingency on a condition.

> "He would have done anything (if condition were true) you asked him
>   to."

It's true as others have suggested that it's simpler to say:

> "He would do anything you asked him to."

But this isn't totally unambiguous, as evidenced by the meaning apparent in:

> "I would do anything you asked me to."

This doesn't necessarily refer to the past. "Would" doesn't have to refer to the past, eg.: "I would go but I don't have the money".

And "asked" doesn't necessarily refer to the past either, as evidenced by its meaning in:

> "If you asked me to jump off a bridge, I'd tell you to go to hell."

It's possible that the most clear way of conveying your desired meaning is to do what FumbleFingers said in their comment, that is, qualify the sentence with extra information as to a time you're referring to:

> "**Back then**, he would do anything you asked him." 
>    - Courtesy of
>   FumbleFingers.

By specifically including "back then", you make an implication that the statement  you make applied earlier, but no longer does. But this is an implication, not a necessity.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 'He would have done anything you had asked him to'?

Comment: And what's the difference between these sentences?

Comment: I would have done anything you HAD ASKED me to! & I would do anything you asked me to!

Comment: @J.J. First of all, I don't see any of your examples as being wrong, though I agree with what's said in the comments that it can and should be simplified, maybe how FumbleFingers suggested. Secondly, I don't know of any rule that's violated by not matching tenses between clauses or within a sentence. Examples: "I did what you've requested." "I've done what you requested." "I've done what you had requested." Finally, as to your question of what's the difference between the two, the first is saying "I would have done" (before), and the second means  "I would do" (now).

Comment: @J.J. I know it's complicated, it's complicated even for me. If I look up what the difference is between the simple past, present perfect or past perfect(pluperfect) the meanings given are often not in consonance with the English I hear or speak, (either formally or informally).

Comment: It is not complicated. “Would” is both modal and auxiliary, so tense/past/present has nothing to do with it - that is handled by the verb coming after “would”. As a modal auxiliary, “would” is marking only conditionality or contingency, not time. Separate those two functions and all the complication disappears.

Answer (score 0):

“Would” is both modal and auxiliary, so tense/past/present has nothing to do with it - that is handled by the verb coming after “would”. As a modal auxiliary, “would” is marking only conditionality or contingency, not time. Separate those two functions and all the complication disappears. – Roaring Fish

Answer (score -2):

**It is the third conditional or the past unreal conditional or past hypothetical conditional**.

1. He would have done anything you had asked him to
2. He would have anything had you asked him to (Inverted conditional).

The third conditional has an if clause and a main clause. The if clause describes a situation that didn't really happen in the past. It uses the past perfect (‘had’ + past participle).
The main clause refers to the result of the unreal imaginary situation in the past. It uses ‘would have’ + past participle.

[https://grammar.ctx.ef.com/conditionals/third-conditional-unreal-past#:~:text=The%20third%20conditional%20has%20an,imaginary%20situation%20in%20the%20past](https://grammar.ctx.ef.com/conditionals/third-conditional-unreal-past#:%7E:text=The%20third%20conditional%20has%20an,imaginary%20situation%20in%20the%20past).

Comment: _Back then, he would / he'd do anything you asked [him to]_. – FumbleFingers /// Please read the first two comments under the question. ELU deals with English **usage**, not (necessarily) what arcane rules seem to suggest.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This is not an "arcane"rule but an established grammatical structure, and the correct answer is the 3rd option.

Comment: Do you still cling to "It is I"?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I cling to grammar rules in general.

Comment: But they change, and they're not universal. "John is taller than I" is now less acceptable conversationally (and usage drives grammar) than "John is taller than me." Ending a sentence with a preposition would have lost you a mark in an essay 60 years ago. _Very_ rarely nowadays. Using sentence fragments was once held by many to be always unacceptable. Perhaps until Churchill spoke of chickens and necks.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, they do but those changes are not so significant and they happen over a long period of time, not overnight. Moreover, the lion`s share of those changes are not related to grammar but lexicon.

Comment: I gave three grammar shifts. They've largely been completed (or readjusted). But there were people protesting (against, if you prefer) those changes for many a long year. Look at FumbleFingers' and Reg Dwight's 'reputations' (and some of their answers) and see if GrammarLab measures up. McCawley, CGEL and Quirk et al are the benchmark texts on ELU. Pullum posts updates on modern usage on LanguageLog.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (Rodney Huddleston and Geoffrey Pullum) is one of my favorite grammar books. As it seems, you`re a prescriptivist.

Comment: Yes. One of my main rules: _Don't follow arcane (ie the ones 90+% of Anglophones don't use) usages._ Or, to paraphrase Orwell, "If something sounds outlandish, break any other rule to avoid it."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The rule I mentioned in one of my previous comments is not old or arcane. You can find it in every contemporary grammar book.

Comment: This is not even about conditionals. "He'll do anything you ask him to" is a deleted version of "He'll do anything that you ask him to" with a that-clause, not an if-clause.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "He would have done anything you had asked him to" is the third conditional.

Comment: OP's question is how to put the non-conditional **statement** 'He will do anything [that] you ask him to [do]' into a past timeframe. _All the examples of the 'third conditional' in the article you link to have an if-clause as protasis. Where is the protasis in 'He will do anything [that] you ask him to [do]'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What makes you think that the missing word is "that" and not "if"?

Comment: The same thing that made FumbleFingers and RegDwight (who offers the idiomatic 'He'd do anything you asked') think this. "He'll do anything, if you ask him [to]' just doesn't get reduced to "He'll do anything you ask him to". _Finis._